# Спарсить с сайта данные JSOUP

Tags: java, парсер, jsoup, xmlparser

Есть такой сайт: http://www.cbr.ru/scripts/XML_daily.asp
С него надо спарсить курс гонконского доллара

Научилась парсить весь сайт:

```
 Document doc = Jsoup
            .connect("http://www.cbr.ru/scripts/XML_daily.asp")
            .get();

Elements valelement = doc.select("#webkit-xml-viewer-source-xml > ValCurs > Valute:nth-child(9)"); - это не работает
System.out.println(doc.html());
```

Как выбрать отдельный элемент? (там куча вложенных тегов, как указать нужный?)

```
Вот этот: <Valute ID="R01200">
<NumCode>344</NumCode>
<CharCode>HKD</CharCode>
<Nominal>10</Nominal>
<Name>Гонконгских долларов</Name>
<Value>99,5819</Value>
</Valute>
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно вытащить по ID :  Element valelement = doc.getElementById("R01200");